# Spring data JPA - Adding custom behaviour to all repositories

Tags: jpa-2.0, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Has anybody successfully implemented [Adding custom behaviour to all repositories](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories) for Spring data? I am unable to figure out the full details and there seems to be [some discrepancy in the documentation and implementation](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/DATACMNS-159). Is there an issue to be corrected? Please share your experiences and details of how to implement JpaRepositoryFactoryBean and a CustomizedRepository Implementation.

Thanks much for all inputs,
RJ

Comment: Hello RJ. Were you able to get "Adding custom behaviour to all repositories" to work? If so can you share some advice/samples?

Answer (score 0):

These glitches have been fixed as documented in the ticket you linked. The actual commit is [here](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-commons/commit/a0bec0fce04af8c798aa269e61eafaa63541601c). It's already released in Spring Data Commons 1.3.0.RC2 so if you checkout that tag and do `mvn docbkx:generate-pdf` should get the correct PDF documentation part rendered. As this documentation snippet from Spring Data Commons is pulled into the documentation of Spring Data JPA it will automatically become part of the next release.

Actually, the relevant snippet has made it into the latest milestone release of Spring Data MongoDB already so you can look it up [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/1.1.0.M1/reference/html/#repositories) as well.

Answer (score 0):

I have a detail post about how to customize the spring data Jpa repository. You can follow the sample code and apply custom behaviour to all repositories.

http://borislam.blogspot.hk/2012/07/customizing-spring-data-jpa-repository.html